# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'step'

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get 3d grid and I use the following command:

```
    x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
    y = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
    z = np.linspace(-10,10,100)

    X,Y,Z = np.mgrid[x, y, z]
```

And such error emerges

```
        AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
          6 
          7 
    ----> 8 X,Y,Z = np.mgrid[x, y, z]
          9 
         10 #X,Y,Z = np.mgrid[-10:10, -10:10, -10:10]

    ~/Desktop/PyProjects/Phys/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py in __getitem__(self, key)
        165             typ = int
        166             for k in range(len(key)):
    --> 167                 step = key[k].step
        168                 start = key[k].start
        169                 if start is None:

    AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'step'
```

I know I can use this form to generate the grid

```
    X,Y,Z = np.mgrid[-10:10, -10:10, -10:10]
```

but it is not mobile for me

Comment: I believe mgrid is just a convenient way to pass slices. Normally the function is meshgrid: `np.meshgrid(x, y, z)`. Does that work for you?

Comment: I am stupid because I didn't know about it. Thanks a lot) it works for me

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it so that others can see it more clearly :)

Comment: Maybe  @user2285236 should do this and get all the credits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try np.meshgrid() instead of mgrid:

```
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
```